# why might a drivers license # be required for a plane trip?

Tags: usa, air-travel

My manager is booking plane tickets for an upcoming conference in another state and he asked me for the following three things:

- my full name as it appears on my drivers license
- my DOB
- my drivers license #

The first two seem reasonable enough but the last item seems...  fishy. I don't think I've ever been asked for a drivers license # when flying. I've been asked for a passport # when traveling internationally but not a drivers license #.

I mean, it seems to me that a drivers license shouldn't even be required for flying. You could be 40yo and not have a drivers license and you could get around exclusively using taxi's, uber's and public transit.

I realize a drivers license can be used to verify your identity to TSA but the documents you're providing to TSA don't need to be pre-registered or anything...

Comment: Is it possible that the manager is booking a rental car for when you arrive at the destination?

Comment: Have you asked your manage why she or he wants this information?

Comment: @David - I did but haven't gotten a response. He asked me on Thursday and then went on vacation on Friday. I can def ask him when he gets back but idk...  he's often very short with me and tells me stuff like "you don't need to know that". I suppose I could be like "well if don't want to tell me why then I don't want to give it to you" but idk...  discussions along these lines are prob best suited for workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is it possible your manager just wants to confirm that you do have an acceptable form of ID before he books the tickets?

Comment: (S)he might want the number the ID you are flying on, and is assuming you'll use your driver license instead of a passport for an internal flight

Comment: @neubert re the comments above?

Comment: @MarkMayo - I never did find out. My company has been in the middle of a move so (1) it doesn't really feel like the best time to ask and (2) enough time has passed such that asking again, more then a week later, feels like it'd be beating a dead horse idk. I mean, I'd still like to know why he wanted it, but I don't plan on asking again unless it comes up.

Comment: In lieu of that and of any solid reason presented here my best guess is that he just asked for my DL # when he meant to ask for my TSA #. ie. my best guess is he screwed up but getting him to admit that he did so is probably not going to be the easiest task and I'm not sure this is a big enough issue to merit "rocking the boat" over.

Comment: @neubert I'd suggest it might be for the domestic flight, that ID was required and more have driver licenses than passports?

Answer (score 2):

It would not be required for a plane trip. If that would be the case then many people wouldn't be able to fly...

Since this is a company trip then maybe the standard paperwork for trips asks for your drivers license number in the case you need a company/rental car one day.